# Http call response comes on calling second time, but not the first time

Tags: angular, http, http-post, google-chrome-devtools

I have a code implemented this way:

```
in component.ts 

getHistoryData() {
    this.generatePayload()
    this.historyDataService
      .getHistoryData(this.payload)
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          const responeData: any = data.dataPoints;
          this.timestampArray = responeData.map(e => e.date.slice(5, 10) + ' ' + e.timestamp.slice(0, 5));
          console.log('temp array' + this.temperatureArray)
          this.temperatureArray = responeData.map(e => e.parameter1 / 100);
          this.dateArray = responeData.map(e => e.date);
        }
      ),console.log('in getHistoryData' + this.temperatureArray)
  }
```

```
and in service .ts 

  getHistoryData(payload : MiloData) {
    console.log(payload)
    return this.httpClient.post(this.appConfig.apiUrl_historydata,payload,httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
```

when i call the getHistoryData for the first time, response is not printed in the console,but when i try to call the getHistoryData again, every thing works as expected.Why is it happening so.

I tried checking in the chrome developer tools, each time i make a call to getHistoryData, two responses come, one with status 204 and then with status 200.

Why is it happening?

[image]

Comment: what is the API doing at server side? Are you sure server is not responsible for this?

Comment: api is working fine. tested with postman

Comment: I get the response from the server side but that is not getting binded with the front end. I have to make an api call again and the response from the call is getting binded